# Issue when refreshing page - Incorrect state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Whenever I reload the browser when in my angular application, I lose the current state of the application. I am generating my routes dynamically based on information I get from a WebApi controller, so it would be pretty complicated to look at, but I can post it if need be.

Basically whenever I refresh the page and setup my states/urls again, this output the current state.

`console.log($state.current);`

This results in this:

`Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}`

which is not a state I am setting up. I can't reproduce this in a smaller website, so a plunkr wouldnt likely reproduce the issue, I am just wondering if anyone has ever seen this phantom state and what causes it?

Edit: Also note that the `$stateChangeStart` does not fire on page refresh.

Comment: The application will lose it's state if the page is refreshed since  the app is initialized all over again. You need to persist the state in the browser - maybe use localStorage or cookies?

Comment: @marcellscarlett If thats the case, how is this sample app working? (Refresh the page while on any nested state and it returns you to your last state) http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/42/item/a

Comment: Look at the source. It's using $stateParams to create the state based off of the URL params. If you're routes are truly dynamic, I'm not sure how you'd do that.

Comment: I'd wager it is able to return the last state because `url: '/item/:itemId'` for a state of `"contacts.detail.item"`....which would ultimately make the full url end up being `"/contacts/{contactId}/item/:itemId"`...and because this is present in the url upon refresh, the it is able to map the route and apply the state